# Python & Windows: Spawning a process, then dying without showing the cmd prompt

Tags: python, windows, console

I've got a problem with a python script which is responsible for syncing changes from a VCS (among other things) which may include changes to itself / libraries it depends on. In such cases, I would like to be able to detect if the sync touched anything I depend on, and restart if that was the case.

On POSIX platforms this is easy. exec(), done. On Windows it's incredibly annoying. I can Popen or exec*() and then die, but the problem is my user will see the cmd prompt show a new line, which messes up the flow of output, not to mention completely breaks any future input on stdin, allows them to run commands while my script is still running, which is undesirable.

I've searched high and low without finding anything approaching an answer to this (and yes, I know there are alternative ways to accomplish the same goal, but it'd be nice to have this work). Seemingly the problem is telling the console that the new process is now the "owner" of the console, but I can't find a way to do that. I tried calling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx through ctypes, and that didn't work either.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It should be fine if you start the script from Explorer or use cmd's `start` command to open a new console. But if the immediate child process of cmd.exe (or any other shell) exits, then of course the shell resumes and both processes access the console at the same time. I don't think there's anything reasonable to do about that. There are unreasonable options, such as suspending the parent process if it's not explorer.exe -- i.e. find the parent name and thread IDs using the tool help API, then `OpenThread` and `SuspendThread`; and `ResumeThread` before exiting from the spawned process.

Comment: Given you agree that drastic measures like the above suggestion are unreasonable, how about simply forcing the spawned process to get a new console? That's easy using `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: A new console isn't the worst option, although it could throw my users for a loop (for context, this is a tool other developers use to run builds/tests) and UX is important in this case.